# How to scroll large datafile while keeping header

Tags: vim, less, scrolling, pager

Suppose I have some large datafile, which overflow the screen in both vertical and horizontal direction. How can I browse this file, while the header-lines stay on the screen?

For the moment, I am using `less -S`, so that I can nicely scroll my file horizontally and vertically. However, when scrolling down, the header lines obviously disappear. Is there a way to keep these using less?

An alternative is using `vim` in split-screen mode with `:set nowrap`. However, now if I scroll horizontally, the top window doesn't scroll in the same way (`:windo set scrollbind` only works for vertical scrolling as far as I know).

Comment: What do you mean by header stays visible, while the data keeps scrolling? Do you mean that you only want the first line with the column names keeps the same? Is it only one file with data and does this data keep changing and therefore you only want to see the changed rows? Do you only want to see the first N rows or last N rows?

Comment: @polym: `less` or `tail -f` that behave exactly like they do normally, except that the first line shown on screen would always be the header line. Like websites (or Excel) with a fixed header but scrolling body.

Comment: @polym ^ whatever he said!

Comment: @polym, Think of how you can freeze a horizontal and vertical view in a spreadsheet. Columns frozen stay in place while scrolling.

Comment: Oh boy, that asks for an extension to less, like a Freeze Pane point. For example --freeze-pane 10,2 would keep 1 line of column headers and 10 columns row header. Horizontal and vertical scrolling would preserve the row and column headers respectively. That would be really cool to use for a psql pager (http://merlinmoncure.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-psql-with-less.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're familiar with vim, this is probably the best option for you. You can enable horizontal-scroll-bind-only by changing `'scrollopt'`:

```
set scrollopt=hor
```

So with `vim -u NONE`, you get the desired behavior with:

```
:set scrollopt=hor
:set nowrap
:1split
:windo set scrollbind
```

You may want to adjust `'sidescroll'` and `'sidescrolloff'` to change how many columns are skipped and how far from the edge skipping starts respectively.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with less? Especially when scrolling through enormous datafiles (too big to load into memory)?

Comment: @NM: See the other answers

Comment: I tried this and when I scroll down the bottom window, the top window scrolls down too

Comment: @DanielSerodio: Something seems to have changed. It works if you set scrollopt to `hor`, see the updated answer

Comment: The updated answer works as expected, thanks for the lightning fast reply :)

Answer (score 20):

On terminals that support setting the scrolling region:

```sh
tailf() ( # args: <file> [<number-of-header-lines>]
  trap 'tput csr 0 "$((LINES-1))"' INT
  tput csr "$((1+${2-1}))" "$((LINES-1))"
  tput clear
  {
    head -n"${2-1}"
    printf "%${COLUMNS}s\n" "" | tr ' ' =
    tail -n "$((LINES-1-${2-1}))" -f
  } < "$1"
)
```

(assumes a shell like `zsh` or `bash` that sets the `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` variables based on the size of the terminal).

Comment: Dude! That is godly! Sorry, couldn't control myself.
Could you direct me to webpages or commands or variables to implement the following functions?

Comment: 1. exit with `q`  
2. scroll down with `up` and `down` keys

Comment: is it possible to piggyback on `less` itself without using `head` and `tail` to redraw the screen each time? I still <3 your solution btw. I am not marking it correct yet because you seem to be editing it and I don't want you to get complacent; complacency is a creativity-killer, I am told! :)

Comment: @DebanjanBasu you can use `less -X` in place of `tail -n ...` above but the "up" key deletes the header there.

Comment: Like I said, if you have any better ideas just point me to that, or better still please tweak your answer further. I had to mark it correct because you **have** answered the question that I initially asked. The idea is to have a `less` environment sandwiched between a header and a footer, to make it a more general tool.

Comment: @DebanjanBasu, you may want to wait a couple of days before accepting the answer to encourage people to post alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

Try this (you'll need to install [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)):

```
multitail -du -t "$(head -n 1 filename)" filename
```

or, for headers longer than one line:

```
multitail -wh 2 -l "head -n 2 filename" filename
```

If you want to follow command output instead of a file:

```
multitail -wh 2 -l "command | head -n 2" -l command
```

or use `-t` as appropriate. Note that you may need to use [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) so your command output appears immediately.

You can use `-D` to disable the display of status lines for the `-wh` forms (it would defeat the purpose of the `-t` form).

Answer (score 2):

Thor's answer didn't mention disabling the vertical "scrollopt", which makes both windows scroll vertically. So for me the complete solution is pasting this into vim:

```
:set scrollopt+=hor
:set scrollopt-=ver
:set nowrap
:1split
:windo set scrollbind
```

Comment: You can set `scrollopt` directly with `:scrollopt=hor` or `:scrollopt=hor,jump`, depending on your preferences. [Here's the VimDoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrollopt') for `scrollopt`.

Answer (score 2):

The bleeding edge version of `less` supports this with the `--header` option.

> **Less version 603 Release Notes**
>
> Version 603 was released for beta testing on 15 March 2022.
>
> These are the differences between version 590 and version 603:
>
> - Add the --header option.
> - Add the --no-number-headers option.
> - Add the --status-line option.
> - ...

Source: https://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.603.html

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I got with `tmux`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session -s main -n 'w1' -d
tmux send-keys -t main:w1.0 "tail -f <(head -n1 $1)" C-j
tmux split-window -v
tmux resize-pane -t 0 -y 2
tmux send-keys -t 1 "tail -n+2 $1|less -S" C-j
tmux attach -t main
```

It's an extension of [user80519's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149606/how-do-i-create-a-simple-tmux-conf-that-splits-a-window) for `tmux` window splitting. Save as `hless.sh`, make it executable and use it like

```sh
hless.sh file
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be a text-mode solution, you could use `yad` to display a list - actually a GTK+ dialog - with named columns. Maybe it has to read the whole file before you can browse, though.