# How do I create a simple tmux conf that splits a window?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to create a simple tmux conf that does the follow.

1. Splits the window/pane/whatever_stupid_terminology horizontally (hsplit)
2. Opens in the top pane `tail -f foo`
3. Opens in the bottom pane `tail -f bar`

How can I do this with tmux.

This is what I've got,

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -s asdf -n myWindow
tmux select-window -t myWindow
tmux split-window "tail -f /var/log/apache2/samperror.log" 
tmux attach-session -t asdf
```

I can't get anything thought to work. So I know it's all wrong. One of the most unintuitive conf files ever

Comment: Your question refers to a tmux configuration file but your example is a standalone shell script; what approach are you actually interested in?

Comment: @jasonwryan thanks for that. I was desperate and I switched from a plain conf file -- which is what I'd prefer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick and dirty command-line that achieves what you want:

```
$ tmux new-session -s asdf -n myWindow -d 'tail -f foo'\; \
       split-window -d 'tail -f bar'\; attach-session
```

There are a few drawbacks to this solution:

- it doesn't scale very well (a few more commands and the result is incomprehensible).
- the two tail commands aren't run in an interactive shell, so if you exit them both, the window `myWindow` will be destroyed (together with the session if you haven't created any more sessions.

---

Here's a shell script that works along the lines that you tried. For me it's always easiest to think about how I would achieve my goal *manually* and then translate that into tmux commands. This might not be the simplest or cleanest way, but it usually works:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# create a new session. Note the -d flag, we do not want to attach just yet!
tmux new-session -s asdf -n 'myWindow' -d

# send 'tail -f foo<enter>' to the first pane.
# I address the first pane using the -t flag. This is not necessary,
# I'm doing it so explicitly to show you how to do it.
# for the <enter> key, we can use either C-m (linefeed) or C-j (newline)
tmux send-keys -t asdf:myWindow.0 'tail -f foo' C-j

# split the window *vertically*
tmux split-window -v

# we now have two panes in myWindow: pane 0 is above pane 1
# again, specifying pane 1 with '-t 1' is optional
tmux send-keys -t 1 'tail -f bar' C-j

# uncomment the following command if you want to attach
# explicitly to the window we just created

#tmux select-window -t asdf:mywindow

# finally attach to the session
tmux attach -t asdf
```

If after some trying you still don't like the `tmux` command and configuration syntax, you might want to look into [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator), a Ruby gem that lets you manage tmux sessions with a simplified and more transparent syntax.

---

In my answer to [Multiple terminals at once without an X server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148623/) you can find a few links to helpful `tmux` resources

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do want to run this from your `~/.tmux.conf`, not an external script, you would append this to your config file:

```
# session initialisation
new -s SessionName -n WindowName 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/samperror.log'
splitw -h -p 50 -t 0 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/other.log'
selectw -t 0
```

Then, when you start tmux with the command to attach to a session, `tmux a`, it will create SessionName with the window split horizontally (`-h`) in half (`-p 50`) running those two commands.

Comment: is there anyway to make the session automagically attach so I can just run `tmux -f tmux.conf`, and if the session already exists it attaches it -- otherwise it initializes and attaches?

Comment: @EvanCarroll That is what the `a` (a contraction of `attach`) is for. You can always write a function, like so: `tmuxa() { [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && { tmux attach -d || tmux -f $HOME/.tmux/conf new -s SessionName ;} }`

Comment: So there is no way to do it from within the .conf file?

Comment: @EvanCarroll that wouldn't really make much sense; it would, among other things, prevent you from opening a separate tmux session.

Comment: Nowdays `tmux new -A -s session_name` will either attach or create a new session.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149729/47116) here is more generic code:

```
tmuxMany(){
    #https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149729/47116
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo usage: sessionName command1 command2 ...
        return 1
    fi
    local sessionName=$1
    local firstCommand=$2
    local secondAndRestCommands=( "${@:3}" )

    tmux new-session -s $sessionName -n 'myWindow' -d
    tmux send-keys -t $sessionName:myWindow.0 "$firstCommand" C-j
    local i
    for i in "${!secondAndRestCommands[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
        local command=${secondAndRestCommands[$i]}
        echo $command

        tmux split-window -v
        local tabNumber=$((i+1))
        tmux send-keys -t $tabNumber "$command" C-j
    done
    tmux select-layout even-vertical
    tmux attach -t $sessionName
}
```

Usage:

```
tmuxMany sessionName "tail -f file" "tail -f file2" htop
```

Will open tmux with 3 panes of equal height.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I launch an editor + REPL now:

```
mux $(basename $(pwd)) \
  "vim $(find src test resources test-resources -type f 2>/dev/null \
    | tr "\n" " ")" \
  "lein repl"
```

I hacked on [Maxim's code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332330/124690) to get a different layout:

```
#!/bin/bash

#https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149729/47116
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo usage: sessionName command1 command2 ...
    return 1
fi
sessionName=$1
firstCommand=$2
secondAndRestCommands=( "${@:3}" )

tmux new-session -s $sessionName -n 'myWindow' -d
WIN="$sessionName:myWindow"
tmux send-keys -t $WIN.1 "$firstCommand" C-j
for i in "${!secondAndRestCommands[@]}"
do
    command=${secondAndRestCommands[$i]}
    echo $i: $command

    tmux split-window -v
    tabNumber=$((i+2))
    tmux send-keys -t $tabNumber "$command" C-j
done
tmux select-pane -t $WIN.1

fixlayout() {
    tmux set-window-option -t $WIN main-pane-width $(($COLUMNS - 80))
    tmux select-layout -t $WIN main-vertical
}
fixlayout
sleep 1 && fixlayout &

tmux attach -t $sessionName
```

Incidentally this guy's [tmux.conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tangledhelix/dotfiles/master/tmux.conf) seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$ chmod +x tmux.conf
$ cat tmux.conf
#!/usr/bin/tmux source-file
new-session -s asdf -n myWindow "tail -f /var/log/maillog"
split-window "tail -f /var/log/messages"
```

When you run `./tmux.conf`, tmux executes each command in turn, creating the layout you requested.

The surprising part is that `tmux -f tmux.conf` only runs the commands in `tmux.conf` for the first session that's created.  If you already have sessions running, the `-f tmux.conf` is silently ignored.  You can work around that with `tmux source-file tmux.conf`.  You can use that in a shebang line, to make it a script.

I've found this technique really helpful.  In the root of each of my project directories, I have an executable `tmux.conf`.  When I start working on that project again, I run `./tmux.conf` to create the work environment that I prefer for that project.