# Pager that would work with header-lines?

Tags: less, pager

Is there any pager, like less, that would allow paging result, but keeping configurable number of lines at the top always?

Example: I run a query that returns many rows from database. Results are single line of headers (column names), "border", and then the records.

Normal pager treat headers as part of the text, which is not optimal, because it's easy to forget name of the column, or their order, when dealing with sufficiently large datasets.

Comment: does this answer the question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60507/how-to-scroll-large-datafile-while-keeping-header

Comment: Looks like it does. Must have entered keywords in search with a typo or something. Thanks.