# 'less' with header line kept at the top

Tags: files, less, read

Just like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60507/how-to-scroll-large-datafile-while-keeping-header) question: I want to open a file with e.g., `less -Sx32 file.dat`, but as I scroll down, keep the top line locked in place. How can I do this with `less`?

Comment: What does that `-Sx32` do?

Comment: @jarno it turns off word wrapping and sets the tab size to 32. It is convenient for viewing large tab-separated data files, which are common in data science.

Comment: Oh, yes it is the same as `-S -x32`.

Answer (score 5):

## It is now possible since [less v600](https://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.600.html) (released on 2022-01-07)

With the `--header` option, so in your case `less --header 1 myfile`
would keep the first line always displayed. Excerpt from the less v608
manpage:

> `--header`
>
> Sets the number of header lines and columns displayed on the screen.
> The value may be of the form "N,M" where N and M are integers, to
> set the header lines to N and the header columns to M, or it may be
> a single integer "N" which sets the header lines to N and the header
> columns to zero.  When N is nonzero, the first N lines at the top of
> the screen are replaced with the first N lines of the file,
> regardless of what part of the file are being viewed.  When M is
> nonzero, the characters displayed at the beginning of each line are
> replaced with the first M characters of the line, even if the rest
> of the line is scrolled horizontally.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71308346/1077650

## How to install, configure and compile a new version of `less`

Get the [latest RECOMMENDED version **here**](https://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html) and [follow the instructions **there**](https://github.com/gwsw/less).

```bash
# prerequisites on Debian 11.6 bullseye - see NB notes below
sudo apt install gcc make libncurses5-dev

# download, configure, compile
wget http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/less-608.tar.gz
tar xzvf less-608.tar.gz
cd less-608
sh configure
make

# Then you can test it!
./less --version
./less --header 1 myfile
```

**NB:** in order to compile `less`, you will need to have `gcc` and `make` packages installed.

**NB:** if `configure failed` with something like `Cannot find terminal libraries`, you need to install `libncurses5-dev` package (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

It requires some changes to `less`. There exists an enhancement request [here in GitHub](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/43). If it was implemented, you could use something like

```
less --freeze-pane 0,1 file.dat
```

to do what you want.