less - how to make it not split lines for lines that are too wide when it starts?
I have output that is very wide (output from a sql query) and that, when I start less, is split into multiple lines, difficult to understand what is what... If I press on the right arrow, less will actually start showing single lines for each line of output and we know that there is stuff to the left and to the right and we can continue using the arrows to move around..... however when I move to the very ferst columns, I get again multiline output so I am missing seeing the first few columns to the left with the single line output format. Is it possible to make less start so that it uses a single line right from the get go?

Can you maybe add a screenshot or something so we can understand better? I am not sure what the desired behavior is here. less normally (or, at least, the implementation of less that I am familiar with) will wrap long lines. Do you want it to not wrap so you don't see the whole thing?

Are you just looking for less -S?

less -S, that puled it off. Do you want to provide it as an answer?

where does that SQL output come from? Many SQL clients actually allow for "human-friendly" output and will produce better readable output than making less not break lines (though of course @terdon's less -S is 100% correct for that).

mysql client... I am requesting all columns from a table. Because of the way I am going into the client (through a script) I am getting column headers misaligned but that is not much of a problem.

that does sound a bit like you'd be best off doing something like mysql … --result-format=json/raw | mlr --ijson --opprint --barred cat | less -S. Even better would be if mlr supported pretty-printing things in tabular cells, wrapping overly long cell contents within a column

matter of fact, I have a python script based on Textual's DataTable TUI widget which consumes a custom format (so, wouldn't be of much use to you; it's literally just the data_table.py example from the above link, but the ROWS aren't hardcoded, but come from parsing  sys.stdin. The modification wouldn't be hard, in your case you'd load data using from json import load; from sys import stdin; data = load(stdin), and you'd modify the add_column code to table.add_columns(data[0].keys()), and the

add_rows would be called on simply an extraction of the values for each row dictionary

@MarcusMüller will check this... thanks for the input.

ah, also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429576/less-with-header-line-kept-at-the-top
